# What is the best way to authenticate user in a Android app?

Tags: android, authentication, oauth, signing, google-authentication

I'm a bit confused about the differents way to authenticate user on Android devices.
What is the best way to authenticate user in a Android app, in order to call a custom server REST API?

**Use GoogleAuthUtil** like described in these documents:

- http://developer.android.com/google/auth/http-auth.html#ExtendAsyncTask
- http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html

Pro:

- Quick login, user has not to type password nor to click on a button

Con:

- Not corss-platform

**Use Google Sign-In** like described on this document:

- https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in#cross-platform_single_sign_on

Pro:

- Cross-platform

Con:

- User has to click on the Google Sign-In button

It's possible to easily combine the two way, GoogleAuthUtil when users use Android device and Google sign*in when users are on other platform ?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with cross platform, if you use GoogleAuthUtil and Google SignIn button they are both for Android. You can use them both to achive this, just authenticate first time with Google SignIn button, and then save account (so it doesn't ask you which account you want to use for authentication) and access token to SharedPreferences and reuse it for next login (without clicking on SignIn button again)